# Equivalent of Excel RRI Function in Power Query

Tags: excel-formula, powerquery

Is it possible to run functions like the RRI function (or the rate function) in Power Query?  For example, I have a number of columns in Power Query with data:

[image]

I would like to create a new column that runs the excel RRI function on these columns and outputs the result in this new column.  Is that possible?  If so, how can I do it?

Here is a link to the RRI and RATE function documentation:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rri-function-6f5822d8-7ef1-4233-944c-79e8172930f4
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rate-function-9f665657-4a7e-4bb7-a030-83fc59e748ce

Comment: Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See also: [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables).

Comment: No. You can duplicate it in powerbi or use M to duplicate the underlying functionality